How to remove space between currency symbol and amount in HTML
How to remove the space between Currency Symbol and Amount?
I was trying to remove the space between the currency symbol and the amount in HTML. But when I am coding it using decimals in HTML, there is a space remaining between the currency symbol and the amount. Please help me in removing it.
I don't want this space between INR sign and amount. Here is my current code:-


<span class="discount">&#8377 4500</span> 




Your symbol should end with a ;. So <span class="discount">&#8377;4500</span>

Like this:


<span class="discount">&#8377<span>4500</span></span>



Or, preferrably, this:


<span class="discount">&#8377;4500</span>



